# Magic sprintf function - how to wrap it?

Tags: f#

I am trying to wrap a call to `sprintf` function. Here's my attempt:

```
let p format args = "That was: " + (sprintf format args)

let a = "a"
let b = "b"

let z1 = p "A %s has invalid b" a
```

This seems to work, output is

```
val p : format:Printf.StringFormat<('a -> string)> -> args:'a -> string
val a : string = "a"
val b : string = "b"
val z1 : string = "That was: A a has invalid b"
```

But it wouldn't work with more than one arg:

```
let z2 = p "A %s has invalid b %A" a b
```

I get compile-time error:

```
let z2 = p "A %s has invalid b %A" a b;;
---------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(7,10): error FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied
```

How can I create a single function which would work with any number of args?

**UPD**. Tomas has suggested  to use

```
let p format = Printf.kprintf (fun s -> "This was: " + s) format
```

It works indeed. Here's an example

```
let p format = Printf.kprintf (fun s -> "This was: " + s) format

let a = p "something like %d" 123
// val p : format:Printf.StringFormat<'a,string> -> 'a
// val a : string = "This was: something like 123"
```

But the thing is that main purpose of my function is to do some work except for formatring, so I tried to use the suggested code as follows

```
let q format = 
    let z = p format // p is defined as suggested
    printf z // Some work with formatted string

let z = q "something like %d" 123
```

And it doesn't work again:

```
  let z = q "something like %d" 123;;
  ----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(30,15): error FS0001: The type ''c -> string' is not compatible with the type 'Printf.TextWriterFormat<('a -> 'b)>'
```

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this to work, you need to use currying - your function `p` needs to take the `format` and return a function returned by one of the `printf` functions (which can then be a function taking one or more arguments).

This cannot be done using `sprintf` (because then you would have to propagate the arguments explicitly. However, you can use `kprintf` which takes a *continuation* as the first argument::

```
let p format = Printf.kprintf (fun s -> "This was: " + s) format
```

The continuation is called with the formatted string and so you can do whatever you need with the resulting string before returning.

**EDIT:** To answer your extended question, the trick is to put all the additional work into the continuation:

```
let q format = 
  let cont z =
    // Some work with formatted string
    printf "%s" z 
  Printf.kprintf cont format
```

Comment: +1 thank you for your suggestion. My situation is a bit more comlex. Could you please take a look at update on the question?

Comment: The main problem is that I don't get how strings like "xxx %s" are converted into `StringFormatter` class and what exactly happens when I write `printfn "%" 12`. Maybe you have any link where it is explained?

Comment: @Rustam - You have to put all the work that you want to do with the formatted string into the continuation. See the extended example.

Comment: Sorry, is that a typo in your `q` function? I don't see how you use the `cont` you defined