# How can I substitute printfn with a noop

Tags: f#, printf

I use pf as an abbreviation of printfn

```
let pf = printfn

// signature:
val pf : (Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a)
```

Can we change pf so that it is a noop and does not output anything? I tried things like

```
let pf<'a> (x : (Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a)) = ()

// signature:
val pf : (Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a)
```

Comment: This question from yesterday is pretty similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442608/how-to-wrap-sprintf-conditionally-in-f

Comment: guess you are right, will dig into that, thx.

Comment: You could redirect stdout to [Stream.Null](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.null(v=vs.110).aspx).  It's a bit heavy handed, though, and inappropriate if you have other output that you don't want to suppress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
> let noprintf f = Printf.ksprintf (fun _ -> ()) f;;
val noprintf : f:Printf.StringFormat<'a,unit> -> 'a

> noprintf "Hello, %s!" "world";;
val it : unit = ()
>
```

Comment: very elegant. the only thing is that noprintf is not a noop but a function that produces no output while the formatting effort still happens before being truncated. performancewise this solution still reduces execution time to less than 1%. thx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution

```
let pf fstring = 
    if false then 
        printfn fstring 
    else 
        fun _ -> Operators.Unchecked.defaultof<'a>;;
```

Note: this does have some problems and wont work in all cases - see comments

Comment: -1. This has 2 problems - 1. it doesn't even compile if your format string has no format slots (e.g. `pf "foo bar"`). 2. It blows up with nullref if your format string has more than 1 slot (e.g. `pf "%d %d" 1 2`).  I struggled with the same problems while figuring out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31444585/1366219)

Comment: looks like a clever appraoch. executing pf "%s %d"  "bugs bunny" 15 throws a null ref exception. will try to elaborate on your suggestion. thx